# Cannot allocate memory moving files over network share

Tags: windows-7, linux, bash, network-shares

I've got a shared folder on my network that holds my music. I recently converted my flac to mp3, and want to move the flac to the network folder. So I mounted the network share with `sudo mount -o username=Robert //192.168.1.56/music /mnt/networkmusic` and then navigated to the folders with flac in them.

Then, in that folder, I made sure that every subfolder was one I wanted moved (they were) and did `for f in *; do sudo mv "$f"/ /mnt/networkmusic; done` which worked and moved a few of them, but then started giving me errors, so I tried it again and it didn't work at all, just gave me this error

`mv: accessing '/mnt/networkmusic': Cannot allocate memory`

The shared folder is on a windows 7 PC. I think I've read that a setting needs changed to allow it to operate more like a server, but I'm not sure where I read that or even how to set it up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the following registry key to `1`;

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\LargeSystemCache`

and set the following registry key to `3`:

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\Size`

found it here: http://www.codenition.com/solving-cannot-allocate-memory-error-on-windows-7-linux-cifs-mounts